# Writing a regex for a td agent

Tags: regex, kubernetes, fluentd

Currently we have the following config for syslog tdagent(fluentd) config and would like to create another field for priority:Error for my log.
How can I do this?

Log:

```
Nov 11 00:18:57 Build01v nagios: SERVICE ALERT: mmj21;Dropwizard MMJ Thread Pool;UNKNOWN;SOFT;1;**Error**: unable to access dropwizard metrics at localhost using port 8001
```

Current config:

```
<source>
  @type tail
    path           /var/log/messages
    pos_file       /var/log/td-agent/var_log_messages.pos
    read_from_head true
    tag            /var/log/messages
    <parse>
      @type regexp
        expression  ^(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<process>[^ ]*): (?<message>.*)$
        time_format %b %d %H:%M:%S
        time_key    time
    </parse>
</source>
```

Output:

```
https://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%5E%28%3F%3Ctime%3E%5B%5E+%5D*+%5B%5E+%5D*+%5B%5E+%5D*%29+%28%3F%3Chost%3E%5B%5E+%5D*%29+%28%3F%3Cprocess%3E%5B%5E+%5D*%29%3A+%28%3F%3Cmessage%3E.*%29%24&input=Nov+11+00%3A18%3A57+Build01v+nagios%3A+SERVICE+ALERT%3A+mmj21%3BDropwizard+MMJ+Thread+Pool%3BUNKNOWN%3BSOFT%3B1%3B**Error%3A**+unable+to+access+dropwizard+metrics+at+localhost+using+port+8001&time_format=%25b+%25d+%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S
```

Records

```
Key     Value
host    Build01v
process nagios
message SERVICE ALERT: mmj21;Dropwizard MMJ Thread Pool;UNKNOWN;SOFT;1;**Error:** unable to access dropwizard metrics at localhost using port 8001
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that maybe,

```
^(?<time>\S* \S* \S*) (?<host>\S*) (?<process>[^:]*): (?<priority>[^:]*):(?<message>.*)$
```

might be what you're trying to write.

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/CfzuNe/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WJnlt2/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/WJnlt2/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: It still gives same result

Comment: @Kumar: Emma is trying to help you, but you will need to be more descriptive if you want further help. You are the only person who can see your screen. So, how did it not help? What did you get? What other things did this excellent answer prompt you to try?

Comment: You are most welcome; I enjoy seeing posts that obviously took time and effort to construct.

Comment: Nevertheless, if your answer solves the immediate (regex) problem - and I have no doubt it does - then I would expect better feedback from the question author. Three weeks with no further communication is normal on Stack Overflow, but it feels like the question has been abandoned.